# Linux: set custom alert/toast/not sure of name

Tags: linux, user-interface, message, alert, toast

Sorry for the wording, I'm referring to the toast (that's how Android calls them) that appears on the top right of the screen when certain events happens.

Examples: a torrent is done (Transmission) or a new song is playing (Banshee)

Does anyone know how to define one inside a script or a program?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is `libnotify` which also has a command line client called `notify-send` that can be used like this:

```
notify-send <summary> <body>
```

Comment: I'm using jessie (Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50-v7+), on raspberry, install notify 'libnotify-bin', but it don't bring any notification! -> notify-send Test "Hello World"

Answer (score 1):

Howabout `zenity` - installed in gnome by default. as always, `man zenity` for more information

```
zenity --info --text "message her..."
```

Comment: That's a pop up window, the answer above is correct, but thank you!

Comment: How to close window automatically after 5 second, for example?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gnome, you probably want: http://developer.gnome.org/libnotify/

I believe that most of the other desktops will respect notifications sent using libnotify, but have to admit to not having tried it.